# Reading a file from resource package

Tags: java, eclipse, file, resources

I have read many posts on here and done many Google searches but I am still unable to read a file from another java package within my current project.

In one of my classes I have the following code, however the input stream is always null. I have tried using the context class loader, as well as many other solutions but to no avail.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "opcodes.txt" );  
System.out.println(is);
```

Another attempt was:

```
InputStream is = ClassName.class.getResourcceAsStream("/resources/opcodes.txt");
```

which also returned null.

Any help or explanation for why I can not find the file within a resource package would be great.

p.s. I am using eclipse if that makes a difference.

EDIT: If I use an OpenFileDialog to find the file, I am able to open and read it, so the file does exist and is not corrupt.

Comment: I succeeded by defining a java class within the package that contains the resource and then calling: class_in_resource_package.class.getResourceAsStream(file_name); from wherever you wish in the code (even from the code of another class in another package), but you'll have to import the class located within the resource package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the getResourceAsStream() method, found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)
says that:
"
Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:

If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
modified_package_name/name
Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').
"

Your first attempt would have succeeded had the resource been located within the same package as the one the class you're invoking the method from is located. Your second attempt fails because, like the documentation says, the name of the file you give ("/resources/opcodes.txt") is replaced by "resources/opcodes.txt". I guess it means that the method will now search for package resources WITHIN the package where the class that invokes the method is located and not outside of it. Since you don't have such an inner package, the method returns null.

A workaround would be to define a class within the package where your resource is located. That class could be empty for all you care. Just call:

```
ClassWithinResourcePackage.class.getResourceAsStream("opcodes.txt");
```

from within the class you currently invoke the method from, and it works.

I also tried to use the ".." syntax I know from command line, but it doesn't work. I think the documentation implies the method is looking for a file within the same package only.

Comment: I tried this and the file still doesn't exist:

    `File f = new File(Formatting.class.getResource( "opcodes.txt").getFile());
System.out.println(f.exists());`

still returns false. The Formatting class is inside the package containing the file opcodes.txt

Comment: However if I go the route, as shown in your answer and use a Scanner to read the file it does work. Not sure why it doesn't work for getResource() but it does for getResourseAsStream() but I will accept this as an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: @logcat The workaround suggested is cool but is highly unrealistic. We do not get to modify the dependencies bundled as a jar already, which renders the solution not usable in the practical scenarios.

Comment: I tried my (original) solution in my application before posting, and it works fine.

Comment: I don't need to modify any dependencies... lost you there.

Answer (score 1):

Resource files are generally placed in `src/main/resources/` directory in your project. These resources are also packed in the `jar` alongside the compiled class files with .class extension.

I have created a sample maven project with the directory hierarchy discussed above. 
[image: project structure]

The resource file `sample-resource.properties` can be accessed in the program as below:

```
    package temp;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ResourceTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            InputStream inputStream = ResourceTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample-resource.properties");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
```

This would read and print the contents of the resource file:
[image]

Comment: Does it also work in eclipse? You're using Android Studio, no? The OP says he use Eclipse and he's trying to access a file located in another package, not in a resources folder.

Comment: It is independent of the IDE. This works even if the resource exists in a different dependency, apart from the current class, just that any public class in the external package has to be used to get the class I.e, externalclass.getclass().getResourceAsStream("resourceFileName").

Comment: I see the resource directory has a different icon than the java directory. What type of directory do I need to add in eclipse?

Comment: It is very important to know exactly where to put the resources. Otherwise (like if I put the resource in just another package called resources), we end up in exactly the starting position of this question, and your code won't work.

Comment: Actually, I think what you did in the answer was to create another package within the package that contains the class file that calls getResourcesAsStream(). At least that's how I imagine it in Eclipse. This approach is of course much better and averts the workaround, but the problem is the OP asked to access the resource from outside the package.

Comment: @logcat again, it works independent of the IDE provided maven project directory structure is honored. infact, i have tried to read the contents of the resource file residing in a different jar than the current project. The directory structure has to be 
Project-directory
- src
   - main
      - resources
         - resource-file-1
         - resource-file-2